# Handle clicks in dynamically generated elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I noticed this pattern a couple of times and started wondering what's actually the right way to handle it.

Let's say I have an array of objects for which I need to generate corresponding clickable elements. In a click handler, I want to have an access to the corresponding object.

```
render() {
  links = this.props.links.map(link => {
    <a
      onClick={this.clickHandle}>
      {link.title}
    </a>
  })
  // ...
}
```

However, with this approach, the `clickHandle` method will be called without any relevant information about the `link` object when the user clicks on the link. So to have an access to the corresponding object, I made use of closure property in `clickHandle` and rewrote it this way:

```
onClick={this.clickHandle(link)}
// ...
clickHandle(link) {
  return () => {
    alert(link)
  }
}
```

While it works as expected, I'm wondering if it's actually the right way to do it. It seems like I'm creating a lot of intermediate functions each time React rebuilds this piece of dom. Is it a bad practice? What are alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are alternatives?

Create a link component that gets the data as props and passes it to the click handler:

```
var Link = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        data: ...,
        onClick: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    },

    _onClick: function() {
        this.props.onClick(this.props.data);
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <a
                onClick={this._onClick}>
                {this.pops.data.title}
            </a>
        );
    }
});
```

Usage:

```
links = this.props.links.map(
    link => <Link key={...} data={link} onClick={this.clickHandle} />
);
```

Comment: The only thing I'd add is that you probably want a `{...this.props}` spread on the `<a />` tag

Answer (score 2):

Even though it still creates intermediate functions, the [React way](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html) is to use `.bind()`.

```
render() {
  links = this.props.links.map(link => {
    <a
      onClick={this.clickHandle.bind(this, link}>
      {link.title}
    </a>
  })
  // ...
}
```

Comment: While yes, this is an easier way of doing what OP describes, it has the same downside in that it creates a new function every time you run `render`.  This is because `.bind` returns a new function.  Is this a problem? probably not for 99% of cases.